# Issue with adding my FileProvider

Tags: android, merge, android-manifest, android-fileprovider, smooch

If I try to add my FileProvider like this:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.myfileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

I got the following issue:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.mergeManifestsForApplication(AndroidBuilder.java:524)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeManifests.doFullTaskAction(MergeManifests.java:143)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
```

If I remove the "authorities" line I get this:

```
 Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS@resource value=(@xml/provider_paths) from AndroidManifest.xml:374:17-55
is also present at [io.smooch:ui:5.12.5] AndroidManifest.xml:50:17-51 value=(@xml/file_paths).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:resource"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:372:13-374:58 to override.
```

I also added `'tools:replace="android:resource"'` but then it just goes back to the old error. What can I do to merge them correctly?

## EDIT:

This is my providers_path.xml  file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

And this is the file I need to take:  `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Passenger/passenger_log.txt";`

What do I need to add in my provider path exactly? Trying to understand the logic of external-path.

At this moment I get this:

```
06-11 11:30:51.483: E/AndroidRuntime(16656): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
06-11 11:30:51.483: E/AndroidRuntime(16656):    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:604)
06-11 11:30:51.483: E/AndroidRuntime(16656):    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:578)
06-11 11:30:51.483: E/AndroidRuntime(16656):    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:416)
06-11 11:30:51.483: E/AndroidRuntime(16656):    at nl.hgrams.passenger.fragments.PSSettingsFragment$3$1$1.onResponse(PSSettingsFragment.java:311)
06-11 11:30:51.483: E/AndroidRuntime(16656):    at nl.hgrams.passenger.utils.Utils$12.onAnimationEnd(Utils.java:552)
06-11 11:30:51.483: E/AndroidRuntime(16656):    at android.view.animation.Animation$3.run(Animation.java:382)
06-11 11:30:51.483: E/AndroidRuntime(16656):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
06-11 11:30:51.483: E/AndroidRuntime(16656):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
06-11 11:30:51.483: E/AndroidRuntime(16656):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
06-11 11:30:51.483: E/AndroidRuntime(16656):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
06-11 11:30:51.483: E/AndroidRuntime(16656):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-11 11:30:51.483: E/AndroidRuntime(16656):    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
06-11 11:30:51.483: E/AndroidRuntime(16656):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

This code is causing the crash, at the FileProvider line:

```
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Passenger/log.zip");
                            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                            emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"support@psngr.co"});
                            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Psngr Android Logs");
                            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Thanks for helping us improve Psngr!\n Please describe the issue you found");
                            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), Constants.PROVIDER_AUTHORITY, file));
                            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Feedback..."));
                            PSApplicationClass.getInstance().showSavingPopup = getString(R.string.email_sent);
```

Comment: @pskink Thanks to Learning Always answer, I did manage to go past that. Now I'm having an issue getting the files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code
this line

```
 android:authorities="${applicationId}.myfileprovider"
```

should be replace by

```
 android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
```

your xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-path
            name="external_files"
            path="." />
<root-path
        name="external_files"
        path="/storage/"/>
    </paths>
```

Comment: it builds now, but I have another question. What path do I need to put exactly in my provider file?
If this is my files path: `files[0] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Passenger/passenger_log.txt";`

Comment: still same issue. trying now to debug. Also added the code where it crashes

Comment: your path should Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Passenger/passenger_log.txt. add tostring after getting external storage.. and try to run after clean build

Comment: I fixed it, and also marked your answer as the correct one. Thanks a lot. this really helped

Comment: It saves my life! I was stuck at how to define the path at the xml file, the official document is not clear. But set path="." always works well.