# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-fileprovider

This is my code block:

```
notificationIntent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context,
            "TrySomething",new File(context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/update_file")
    ),ANDROID_PACKAGE);
```

And this is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="myupdater" path="files/update_file"/>
</paths>
```

But i get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root
>   that contains /data/data/com.example.trysomething/files/update_file

How can I fix it?

Comment: Look at this for how to implement file provider. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794378/issue-with-adding-my-fileprovider/50794484#50794484

Comment: i tried it sir. but i didn't success..

Comment: did you follow every steps?? because I saw that your XML file is not look a like required XML.. Please check twise

Comment: yes sir the codes are same or not ? what is mine mistake tell me if the code block is wrong.

Comment: Look at the ans.. had added step by step implementation

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

First Create Xml File inside src->xml folder Like 
for example named `file_paths_public.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-path
            name="external_files"
            path="." />
<root-path
        name="external_files"
        path="/storage/"/>
    </paths>
```

then Add this Code in to your manifest file

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="<your app package>.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths_public" />
    </provider>
```

now create one function that will support both api 26 and below device
that returns some valid uri

```
 public static Uri getUriFromFile(Context theCtx, File theSrcPath) {
        Uri requirdUri;

        // Above Compile SDKversion: 25 -- Uri.fromFile Not working
        // So we have to use Provider

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            requirdUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(theCtx,
                    theCtx.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",
                    theSrcPath);
        } else {
            requirdUri = Uri.fromFile(theSrcPath);
        }

        return requirdUri;
    }
```

now use this uri Whenever you want 
like

```
 File FilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()/update_file/<here your file name >
   Uri shareImageUri = getUriFromFile(this, <your full file Path Add hear>)
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Check if you have this in your manifest

   ```
   <provider
   android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
   android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
   android:exported="false"
   android:grantUriPermissions="true">
   <meta-data
   android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
   android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
   </provider>
   ```
2. provider_paths:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <paths>
   <external-path name="directory_name" path="."/>
   </paths>
   ```
3. Get file URI as

   ```
   Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", fileName(FILE))
   ```

Comment: the step 3 getUriForFile function want a file not fileName. when i get the file like that 
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/update_file");
i get some error

Comment: where do you save the file

Comment: When you try to save the file ... save that file instance and try to pass that to the getUriForFile function